# Attempting to join and group data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.  The first is `property` and the second is `category`

The structure of the `property` table is:

```
id  propertyname
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
```

and the structure of `category` is:

```
id   propid   catid
1      1         2
2      1         3
3      2         1
4      3         1
5      3         2
6      4         3
```

I'm trying to create a result like this:

```
id   propertyname propid     catid
1       a           1         2,3
2       b           2         1
3       c           3         1,2
4       d           4         3
```

How can I get this result?  I used a `group by` clause and `group_concate()` function but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT prop.*,category.property_id cat_prop,category.type_id type 
FROM tbl_property prop,
tbl_category_type category 
WHERE prop.id=category.property_id
```

Comment: can you share with us what queries have you tried so far and the results they offer?

Comment: `i use group by clause and group_concate() function but it does not work` - please show your sql statement

Comment: SELECT prop.*,category.property_id cat_prop,category.type_id type FROM `tbl_property` prop,tbl_category_type category WHERE prop.id=category.property_id                                                                                                            this is the query which i used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.propertyname, group_concat(t1.catid) 
FROM t0 
INNER JOIN t1 ON t0.id = T1.propid
GROUP BY id
```

That should give you your result

Comment: sorry, was my mistake. I forgott the GROUP BY clausel. try it again